# Enable checkboxes within Chrome using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

On a frequent basis I have to visit a site which by default disables a set of checkboxes which I need to then enable (normally via copying the page's html using Chrome Inspector - and doing a find and replace on the 'disabled' reference).

When I open up the page source, the script they are using to disable the checkbox looks like this:

```
    function CheckboxFormatterMultipleCheck(cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{       
    var relationshipCheckDetail =  rowObject[1] +"|"+rowObject[2];
    var checkbox = '<input  id="'+options.rowId +'_chkIsLookedUp" type="checkbox" ' +  (cellvalue == "False"? 'disabled' : '') +' name="'+ relationshipCheckDetail +'" class="isLookedUp"/>';

    return checkbox;
}
```

which then translates to this when using the Chrome inspector on the site in question:

```
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align:Center;" title="" aria-describedby="jGrid_IsLookedUp"><input id="0_chkIsLookedUp" type="checkbox" disabled="" name="7e4a0403-f328-46d2-ba15-80c617ea4d8a|13118725" class="isLookedUp"></td>
```

I am trying to write a very basic Chrome extension to automate the above steps to either 'enable' the checkbox, or to delete the 'disabled' reference which has the same effect.

I have created the manifest and have the extension operating on the site I want, but i'm struggling with the Javascript side to get the checkboxes enabled. My best guess was:

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("checkbox").removeAttribute("disabled");
}
}
```

but this does not appear to work. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just programmatically click the checkbox

`document.getElementById("checkbox").click();` in general it will work if the site has not make check on untrusted events
 read more here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted